# Asymptote: Planar surface from path - misdrawn streaks at corners

Tags: asymptote

I have a question regarding Asymptote. I experience a problem when I use Asymptote to draw planar surfaces defined from cyclic paths, as illustrated with the example below. When I draw the surface, odd streaks are visible near the corners of the surface.

```
settings.outformat="png";
settings.render=8;
size(8cm, 0);
import three;

currentprojection = orthographic(0,0,-1,up=-Y,zoom=0.937);

real r=3;
real c = 5;
real w = 1;

pair Pynp = (-w/2, c/2);
pair P1np = (-w/2, w/2);
pair Pxnp = (-c/2, w/2);
pair Pxnn = (-c/2, -w/2);
pair P1nn = (-w/2, -w/2);
pair Pynn = (-w/2, -c/2);
pair Pcyn = (0, -c/2);
pair Pcyp = (0, c/2);

path outline = arc((0,0), r, 90, 270) -- Pcyn -- Pynn -- P1nn -- Pxnn -- Pxnp -- P1np -- Pynp -- Pcyp -- cycle;

path3 outline3 = path3(outline);

surface s = surface(outline); 

draw(outline3, black + linewidth(2));

draw(s, red);
```

As seen in the example above, the surface is defined from a cyclic 2D path, which consists of an arc and a number of line segments.

Could you please let me know if this is a known problem, and if there is anything that I can do to solve the problem?

I am using Asymptote 2.41 on a Windows 10 platform.

This is a screenshot from the OpenGL render. The black streaks are clearly visible in two of the corners. The streaks are also present in the PNG-file which I generate directly from the asy-file.

[image: This is a screenshot from the OpenGL render. The black streaks are clearly visible in two of the corners. The streaks are also present in the PNG-file which I generate directly from the asy-file.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure to explain the problem. Perhaps in the 3D renderer, degenerate triangle or Bezier patch ?
I tried the command `Arc` (with capital A) from `graph.asy` which can produce circular arc with more accuracy. The number of nodes of the circular arc being different, the triangulation of `outline` (required to create the surface) is different and with Asymptote svn (more or less) on Linux 64bits, it seems to be ok.
Here the code

```
size(8cm, 0);
import graph;
import three;

currentprojection = orthographic(0,0,-1,up=-Y,zoom=0.937);

real r=3;
real c = 5;
real w = 1;

pair Pynp = (-w/2, c/2);
pair P1np = (-w/2, w/2);
pair Pxnp = (-c/2, w/2);
pair Pxnn = (-c/2, -w/2);
pair P1nn = (-w/2, -w/2);
pair Pynn = (-w/2, -c/2);
pair Pcyn = (0, -c/2);
pair Pcyp = (0, c/2);

path outline = Arc((0,0), r, 90, 270,10) -- Pcyn -- Pynn -- P1nn -- Pxnn -- Pxnp -- P1np -- Pynp -- Pcyp -- cycle;

path3 outline3 = path3(outline);

surface s = surface(outline3); 

draw(outline3, black + linewidth(2));

draw(s, red);
```

and the result

[image]

O.G.

Comment: O. G.: Thanks a lot for your advice. Using the command "Arc" (with capital "A") from the graph.asy (or graph3.asy) package solved my problem.